# How to handle optional windows in Autoit?

Tags: windows, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation, autoit

I am automating a software installation in Windows7 using AutoIt.

During the installation, in between if  a error window appears. I want to click ENTER.

If the error window not appears then I should NOT do anything. Simply its should go to the next section.

I have tried "WinActive and WinWaitActive" But its waiting for the window to appear. If window not appears its not going to the next screen.

Any idea how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Do a while loop:

```
$w = 0
While($w = 0)

If(WinActive("ERROR WINDOW"))Then
    Send("{ENTER}")
    $w = 1

ElseIf(ControlGetText("YOUR WINDOW", "", "[CLASS:Static; INSTANCE:2]") <> "SOME TEXT") Then
    $w = 1
;and something else
EndIf

Sleep(1000)

WEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

`AdlibRegister()` is the right choice. From the help file:

> "... typically to check for unforeseen errors. For example, you could use adlib in a script which causes an error window to pop up unpredictably."

Each 100 ms (may be adjusted) the function is called to check the appearing of your error dialog:

```
Global $sErrorWindow                    = 'ErrorDialogName'
Global $iDelayHowOftenDoTheFunctionCall = 100

AdlibRegister('_isErrorWindowDisplayed', $iDelayHowOftenDoTheFunctionCall)

Func _isErrorWindowDisplayed()
    If WinActive($sErrorWindow) <> 0 Then
        WinActivate($sErrorWindow) ; just to be sure that the ENTER command is on the correct window/dialog

        ; either do
        Send('{ENTER}')
        ; or
        ControlClick('title', 'text', 'controlID')
    EndIf
EndFunc

; do your software installation processing here
; ...
; ...

; don't forget to unregister the function at the end
AdlibUnRegister('_isErrorWindowDisplayed')
```